# WSO2 ESB, and different response types for the same call

Tags: wso2, esb

I am using `WSO2 4.9`.
I have a simple endpoint defined as such

```
<endpoint name="someEndpoint">
    <address uri="someAddress" format="soap11">
</endpoint>
```

This specific endpoint also requires basic HTTP auth, which I provide like this:

```
<property name="Authorization" description="Set-User-Pwd" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', $ctx:authorizationProperty)" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
```

I make a simple call towards it like this:

```
<call description="Some description">
    <endpoint key="someEndpoint"/>
</call>
```

I should note that the server which I'm attempting to call:

- responds with a SOAP answer (i.e. proper XML, etc) when all is good
- responds with a HTML answer when authorization errors happen

The problem I'm having concerns the situation when I'm passing it a wrong user. I'm expecting that in this scenario, my fault sequence would get invoked (the above is part of an `api` declaration, which also has a fault sequence).
But this doesn't happen, and I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </body>; expected </HR>.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1054]
```

I suspect this is happening because `WSO2` attempts to parse my HTML response as if it were XML, and fails (which is understandable). I also suspect that this happens before any error sequence gets invoked, etc, and hence my problem.

**Edit1**: At the beginning of my `outSequence`, I have a log line which isn't getting printed. So I don't think this is something caused by whatever mediators are in `outSequence`.

```
        <outSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="OUT call!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" />
            </log>
            ...
        </outSequence>
```

**Edit2**: Some more details about `inSequence`.
It contains these lines, which seem to make no difference on the error message (i.e. I get the same if I remove).

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/xml"/>
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" value="application/xml"/>
<property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove" />
```

What can I do in this situation in order to be able to catch these errors? I should note that I don't particularly care about the text in the body (I'm only interested in HTTP status code and maybe HTTP status message).

Comment: There must be some content aware mediator (in out-sequence) which builds the response message. Can you post your entire API/Proxy?

Comment: I've edited my question: I have a log line at the beginning of `outSequence` which isn't getting printed at all; I also tried removing everything but the log line from `outSequence` and still the same result.

Comment: Better if you can post the complete synapse file.

Comment: I understand, but I can't. This is for some people who are paranoid about security; also, this stuff is in multiple files, so I'd have to post a lot.
I'm willing to post choice pieces, if it helps.